# Why does adding a particle system to an active rigid body object stop the simulation from playing?

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

So I have a fairly simple rigid body simulation going on. Shooting 3 spheres at a constrained model shed.

I want to create particles for the moment each sphere hits and exits the shed.

First sphere - add these 2 particle systems all fine.

Second sphere - adding the particle system causes all rigid body objects to reset to their 0 position. Remove the particle system and everything jumps back to its correctly simulated position.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug? Any help much appreciated.

MacOS, macbook pro 2012, Mojave. 
Tested the above on 2.80 official and latest 2.82 alpha. Exactly the same results.

[image: Before adding particle system]

[image: After adding particle system. Same frame. No other changes]